# Can't connect to network drive through MS-Dos

Tags: windows-10, networking, command-line

In Windows 10 we have a server that getted mapped on a virtual F: drive.
I'm trying to achieve something with the hardlink thing in MS-Dos and I have to link to a file that is on the server.
But strangely I can't find a way how to connect to this file / drive / server.
In my Windows explorer I see these things about this "server / drive":

[image: Explorer - "my computer"]

[image: Explorer - "this network"]

In MS-Dos when I try "**f:**" I have the error `The system cannot find the drive specified`

In MS-Dos when I try "**\\srv2019**" I have the error `The syntax of the file name, folder or volume name is incorrect` (or something like this, I translated the error)

In MS-Dos when I try "**\\10.0.0.10**" I have the error `The syntax of the file name, folder or volume name is incorrect` (or something like this, I translated the error)

In MS-Dos when I try **ping 10.0.0.10** I get a reply from.

I guess the problem will be something with credentials ? I run the RUN window in Administrator mode btw.
Any help please ?

Comment: try dropping the folder or file onto your command line

Comment: @Jasen nothing happens (network file or local file) when I run the DOS window in administrator mode, but in user mode it completes the link. Strangely a folder from the network says "is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." but the direct link to the shortcut works.

Comment: So trying with that drag / drop thing when trying my command I now have the error : `Local NTFS volume are required to complete the operation`. Admin or user mode. You have any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: Windows it not really my thing,